# Align multiple FloatingActionButtons with different sizes - Android

Tags: android, xml, floating-action-button

I am trying to add two `FloatingActionButton`s to my application. I added two of the with a plain `View` in between and that works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_go" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/dummy"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/fab"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/dummy"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/cancel_fab"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This places two `FloatingActionButton`s and it looks okay. But I wanted the cancel button to be smaller so I added this line:

```
app:fabSize="mini"
```

Now, I get the look I want, but the only issue is, that the mini `FloatingActionButton` appears to the right and I would like it to be aligned to the center of the bottom button.

[image]

Comment: You might try setting the cancel FAB's `layout_anchorGravity` to `top|center_horizontal`. Also, just FYI, before somebody else comes along and rants about it, the design guidelines recommend only one FAB per screen.

Comment: Oh, wait, that's not gonna work, since you have it anchored to the dummy `View`. Have you tried it without the dummy, adding a bottom margin on the cancel FAB?

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I have and it doesn't give any margin between them

Comment: Okay, I read the docs about the FAB and you are right, it is recommended only one per screen. I will just remove it and add it as something else :)

Comment: Cool. Sounds good. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mike mentioned in the comments, it is not advisable to have multiple `FloatingActionButton`s in an activity. I read the docs and I learned something I didn't know. I went with a different layout instead.